# Search and replace specific lines for a build configuration from Xcode scheme file

Tags: ios, regex, xcode, sed

Some background.
I have an Xcode project, I have at present three build configurations (AdHoc, Debug, and Release),but may well add one more. The build configuration used for an archive build of the project is defined in the Archive section of the scheme.

I use xcodebuild as part of a Jenkins job, and use the -configuration option to specify the Build Configuration to use.

I have found that the "clean" command (xcodebuild clean blah.blah.blah) respects the -configuration option however the archive command does not, it will use whatever is specified in the Archive section of the scheme.

Therefore, if I want to change a build from whatever it is set to, say from AdHoc to Release, I'd need to modify the scheme.

I have come up with a sed command that will look in the scheme file and replace any occurrences of buildConfiguration = "Adhoc" with buildConfiguration = "Release" which is:

```
my_build_configuration="Release"
sed -i '' -e 's/buildConfiguration = "[^"]*"/buildConfiguration = "'$my_build_configuration'"/' path/to/file
```

The problem is this applies it not only for the ArchiveAction item, but all items (Build, Run, Test, etc...) I would like, if possible, to specifically target the Archive action, but I'm unsure how to do this using sed.

Here is what I'd like to search for:

```
   <ArchiveAction
  buildConfiguration = "Adhoc"
```

I'd then want to replace just the value in the double quotes, e.g.; change AdHoc to Release, so it would look like

```
   <ArchiveAction
  buildConfiguration = "Release"
```

I'm not quite sure where to begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SeanN I have a working solution on OS X:

```
`sed -i '' -e '/<ArchiveAction/,/<\/ArchiveAction/ s/buildConfiguration = "[^"]*"/buildConfiguration = "'$my_build_configuration'"/' /Path/To/File`
```

Thanks to everyone with their help on this, it's all greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should load a line into the buffer (assuming it is always in 2 line)

```
sed "/<ArchiveAction/ {
   N
   s/\(buildConfiguration = \"\)[^\"]*\"/\1${my_build_configuration}\"/
   }
   " path/to/file
```

if not first try on same line, if failed load the next and retry

```
sed "/<ArchiveAction/ {
   s/\(buildConfiguration = \"\)[^\"]*\"/\1${my_build_configuration}\"/
   t
   N
   s/\(buildConfiguration = \"\)[^\"]*\"/\1${my_build_configuration}\"/
   }
   " path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot get it to work on OS X - Mavericks in this case. I see the following error:

sed: 1: "/<ArchiveAction/ { N s/ ...": extra characters at the end of N command

Comment: does not have an OSX to test but there is not an option like --posix (same as traditionnal GNU sed) ?

Comment: I have had a look and it seems that OS X sed does not support --posix, or I cannot figure out how to do it. Thanks for your help though, much appreciated.